# Rust abstraction over different types of network connections

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I was recently working with a Go project and a Rust project, and noticed that in Go's standard library there is a [`net.Conn`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Conn) interface that represents "a generic stream-oriented network connection," such as a UDP connection, a TCP connection, or a TLS-over-TCP connection.

I'm wondering if there is something similar to this in Rust. I'm interested in the async ecosystem, so I looked at `tokio::net::{TcpStream, UdpSocket}` and `async_std::net::{TcpStream, UdpSocket}`, but they don't seem to implement some common trait.

If I want to abstract over at least the aforementioned three types of network connections, is there some abstraction like a trait in the stdlib or elsewhere that I can use?

Comment: Given that TCP is stream oriented while UDP is message oriented, I wonder what the Go interface looks like and how it even makes sense to handle these the same way.

Comment: @mcarton https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Conn

Comment: Nobody uses UDP that way. TCP and UDP have distinct requirements, and it makes no sense to expect to send the same stream of data without knowing the underlying protocol. For example, UDP has packet loss and TCP does not. It would be unreliable to send UDP data directly like a stream.

Comment: The first sentence of the linked documentation: "`Conn` is a generic stream-oriented network connection." Yet, `UDPConn` indeed implements this interface, which is surprising. I wouldn't go as far as @SOFe and claim that _nobody_ uses UDP for streaming data – in fact it's rather common for real-time applications – but it is very unusual to classify UDP as a stream-oriented rather than a message-oriented protocol.

Comment: (To clarify, I actually fully agree with what @SOFe said – even if you stream data via UDP, you need to know that you are using UDP.)

Comment: @SvenMarnach That makes sense. For context, the Go library I mentioned implements a STUN client on top of `Conn`, and the STUN RFC specifies retry mechanism.

Comment: @ZizhengTai But then retry mechanism.on TCP is a waste of bandwidth.

Comment: @SOFe Well the protocol specifies different retry mechanisms for TCP and UDP. But you're right that I need to handle TCP and UDP quite differently anyway.